# geometry theorems on triangles

Tags: geometry

Having _________ in common is NOT proof that 2 triangles are congruent

a) 2 angles and the included side

b) two sides and the included angle

c) 2 angles and one excluded side

d) 3 sides

e) none of the above

Based from my geometry book, I think the answer is e. Is this correct?

Comment: You are going to have to be much more specific. Theorems about what? What about the angles and sides?

Comment: Side angle side (SAS, AAS, SSS, etc)

Comment: These are theorems on geometry and this is a multiple choice question so I am to select one of the following choices above

Comment: Yes, but what is the question...?

Comment: Think carefully about c...

Answer (score 1):

Part c is the correct choice. Two triangles might have two angles equal (which means all angles are equal, that is, the triangles are similar) and two sides equal, *without* being equal themselves.

For instance, you may have $ABC\cong A'B'C'$ (meaning the angle $A$ is equal to the angle $A'$, etc...) and $AB=B'C'$. If you had $AB=A'B'$, then yes, the triangles would be equal; now however they need not be.

The word *excluded* is also key here. There are two excluded sides, so we can't tell which matches to which...